# How do I exit extrude?

Tags: edit-mode

When Blender starts, the default cube appears in object mode. If I tab into edit mode, and right click onto the cube, and then drag - it extrudes without my pressing E or clicking on the extrude button. Also, the extrude button is hi-lighted at all times. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Make sure your keyboard does not have a keypress this happen to me some time ago hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

When you drag with RMB, you **move** the selection.

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to leave the mode without changes.

If you want to select without moving, you've to release the button immediatly.
If you extruded (<kbd>e</kbd>), you'll **add** new vertices.
[image]